# Build Apache httpd RPM from source fails

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build Apache httpd RPM from the source tarball as mentioned in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html

However, it always fails with the error "libtool:   error: require no space between '-L' and '-R'"

Complete Error :

```
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc           -o htpasswd  htpasswd.lo passwd_common.lo       -L -R -laprutil-1 -ldb-5.3 -lexpat
/usr/lib64/libapr-1.la -lpthread -lcrypt
libtool:   error: require no space between '-L' and '-R'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:48: htpasswd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/httpd-2.4.58/support'
make[1]: *** [/httpd-2.4.58/build/rules.mk:75: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/httpd-2.4.58/support'
make: *** [/httpd-2.4.58/build/rules.mk:75: all-recursive] Error 1
```

Tried Building older version and get the same error and did not find anything when searching for similar errors.

Any help on what this could be?

Comment: This was already answered in  [httpd user mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/list?users@httpd.apache.org:lte=1M:Build%20Apache%20httpd%20RPM%20from%20source%20fails) it seems

Comment: @daniel-ferradal 
Haven't got a solution yet. The suggestion in the mailing list about libtool version did not work, it is already on the latest version.

Comment: Isn't this the point ? -> "The problem here is not the space, but the fact that -L requires a
directory as an argument - like -L/usr/local/lib - and consumes the
following argument (in this case -R) instead."

Comment: Yes, that's the problem but haven't found a solution to it. I'm just using configure to generate the MakeFile and installing the dependencies as required. Also, I'm not sure where is that coming from as these are populated from some variables, so I cannot just edit the Makefile after configure and get it to work.